# Inserting data from and to the same table - IN or INNER JOIN?

Tags: performance, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization

In an application I have 2000 Accounts. The first Account contains 10000 Clients, which is the maximum limit for an Account. Users can select Clients from the first Account and then select some Accounts to copy the selected Clients to the selected Accounts. So the possible maximums are 1999 Accounts and 10000 Clients.

Currently I’m looping over the Account list and calling a Stored Procedure in each iteration from the client application. With each iteration, an Account Id and a table-valued parameter, that contains the list of ids of the clients, are passed to the SP. While testing with 500 Accounts and 10000 Clients, it takes 25 minutes, 34 second and 543 milliseconds. At some point within the SP I’m using the following code –

```
INSERT INTO Client
SELECT AccountId, CId, Code, Name, Email FROM Client
WHERE Client.Id IN(SELECT Id FROM @clientIdList)
```

where `@clientIdList` is the table-type variable that contains the 10000 Client's Id.

The thing is, after each iteration 10000 new Client data is being added to Client table. So, with each iteration, this `INSERT` operation is gonna take longer in the next iteration. Googling for some SP performance tips I came to know that the `IN` clause is considered somewhat evil, and most people suggests to use `INNER JOIN` instead. So I changed the above code to –

```
INSERT INTO Client
SELECT c.AccountId, c.CId, c.Code, c.Name, c.Email FROM Client AS c
INNER JOIN @clientIdList AS cil
ON c.Id = cil.Id
```

Now it takes 25 minutes, 17 seconds and 407 milliseconds. Nothing exciting, really!

I’m new to Stored Procedures arena. So, with this amount of data, is it supposed to take this long? And which one should I consider for the given scenario, `IN` or `INNER JOIN`? Suggestions and performance tips are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: It is very likely that SQL Server generated exactly the same query plan for both statements.

Comment: @FilipDeVos: so, this is the Maximum performance i can get?

Comment: Please try create temp table (#clientIdList) with noncluster index on the ID column. Test you sp with temp table. This will add some performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what is going on without knowing more about your stored procedure.

What I would recommend is checking the Execution plan.  To do this, open up SQL Server Management studio.  In a new query window make a call to your stored procedure passing in any relevant parameters.

Before you execute this, go up to the Query menu and choose the Client Side Statistics and the Actual Execution Plan menu items.

Now run your query.

Come back in 25 minutes when it's all done and there should be 3 or 4 tabs at the bottom (depending on if it returns data or not.)  1 Tab for results, 1 Tab for messages, 1 tab for the client stats and 1 tab for the execution plan.

The client stats tab is useful for seeing if the changes you make affect performance (it keeps several of your last runs to show you how it performed over those.)

The more interesting tab is the execution plan tab. Look at this one, it should look something like this:
[image]

Here it tells me that my query was able to use the primary key index on all my tables. You want to look out for whole table scans (because that means it's not using an index.) Also, if my query hadn't been so simple and had taken a long time, and not used an index then below "Query 1" there would be green text stating "Missing Index" or something along those lines. It will tell you the index you need to create to improve performance.

Also notice it tells you how much each query took, in percentage. I had one query so obviously it took 100% of the time. But if you had 5 queries in your sproc and one took 80% of the time, you might want to check that one out first.

It also tells you how much time was spent on each part of the query, again in percentages. That can be helpful for trying to understand what it is that your query is doing.

Run through this and I'd guess you have other problems with your sproc, and you can ask follow up questions from that.

Comment: I *REALLY* like the way you provided the details (+1 for that) and appreciate it.That'll surely help me learn to find out bottlenecks in SP. The actual requirement is a bit more complex than I mentioned and I wasn't sure if it'll be a good idea to post a 50+ line SP. But if it help finding some performance bottleneck I'll post it. Thanks again.

Comment: I wasn't saying to post the whole SP (and 50 lines, sadly, isn't that large.) But after you run through these steps, you might see a few other places that need optimization. If it's not obvious how to fix, then post that section and see if anyone can help.